# Using Emmet feature for html, css within php file in Visual Studio Code editor

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, emmet

If i code on .php file

```
<div id= ~~
emmet => idate, idn_to_ascii, idn_to_utf-8 ... etc
```

If i code on .htmlfile

```
<div id= ~~
emmet => id
```

I use html,css,js emmets on .html file.
But i can't use html,css,js emmets on .php file.

If you know about this problem, please comment to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emmet doesn't recognize the context in other file types than .html, .css and .js, so you should point it to. 
Use the `emmet.includeLanguages` setting.

Example:

```
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "php": "html"
    },
```

Check the detailed docs for Visual Studio Code for using Emmet in other file types

source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_emmet-abbreviations-in-other-file-types

The only thing is that `emmet.includeLanguages` doesn't support one to many mapping yet, so you can map to only one entity, either html or css 
(issue source: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/62910).